# Using Python to Automate Creation/Manipulation of Excel Spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel

I have some data in CSV format that I want to pull into an Excel spreadsheet and then create some standard set of graphs for. Since the data is originally generated in a Python app, I was hoping to simply extend the app so that it could do all the post processing and I wouldn't have to do it by hand. Is there an easy interface with Python to work with and manipulate Excel spreadsheets? Any good samples of doing this? Is this Windows only (I'm primarily working on a Mac and have Excel, but could do this on Windows if necessary).

Comment: This would be better suited to http://www.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Is this the first occurence of a SU question beloning on SO? If so, congrats!

Comment: Not by a long shot, unfortunately ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[xlutils](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils) (and the included packages `xlrd` and `xlwt`) should allow your Python program to handily do any creation, reading and manipulation of Excel files you might want!

Comment: Please folks READ the OP's question ... the xl* packages DON'T SUPPORT GRAPHS.

Comment: Hello hello ... the person with the equally erroneous Java-packages solution has deleted his answer ...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you could use the [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package to create an Excel COM Object and then manipulate it from a script. You need to have an installed Excel on that machine though. I haven't done this myself so I can't give you and details but I've seen this working so can at least confirm that it's possible. No idea about OS X, unfortunately.