# How can I manipulate excel data in python?

Tags: python, excel

I was wondering if instead of going and learning VBA which I dont really like, can I do something similar with python? For windows there is DataNitro which looks like what I am referring to, but I have a Mac, is there any other way? Is datanitro the only option? I'm not looking to start a debate, just some option if any.

Comment: `can I do something similar with python?` [Yes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1140311/3853289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Interacting_with_Excel

Many people use the IronPython tool, which is .NET compatible or something like that.

> Excel (which exposes a COM automation interface) is accessible to .NET
>   languages like IronPython through the .NET COM interop facilities.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceByName('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0,    
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c') from Microsoft.Office.
Interop import Excel

ex = Excel.ApplicationClass()   
ex.Visible = True
ex.DisplayAlerts = False   

workbook = ex.Workbooks.Open('foo.xls')
ws = workbook.Worksheets[1]

print ws.Rows[1].Value2[0,0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of Python modules to manipulate Excel file here : https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=excel&submit=search

In particular, xlrd (read Excel files) and xlwt (write Excel files).

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly not the most elegant way and may raise issues when opening the data again in excel, but you could save it as a csv and then:

```
import csv
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html